# PNG image bad display xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

So I downloaded this start button image:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E6Xv.png)

I want to make a button with this as the image.I added the image to the project as an embedded resource , and then I did this:

```
this.StartBtn.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromResource("Fitness_App.Resources.Images.start.png");
```

while the xaml file looks like this:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Label Text="The workout you have chosen consists of:"/>
        <ListView x:Name="Presentation_ListView"/>
        <Button x:Name="StartBtn"/>
</StackLayout>
```

this is the result: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVRV8.png)
Any idea how I could make that start png fit nicely?Since it is a png i thought all the other stuff would dissapear.Thanks!

Comment: The other stuff is actually part of your image, it is not transparent...

Comment: Also you would like to cut the image. It has a lot of extra white space (and not transparent)